# Jenkins Docker Pipeline override working directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have noticed when using Jenkins with the Docker Pipeline plugin. When I create a Jenkins file to run commands in a docker container that it always creates a volume mapping of the Jenkins workspace directory mapped to the same path in the running container. It also creates a working directory with the same path.

```
docker run -t -d -u 127:134 -w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest:rw,z 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest@tmp:rw,z 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
jekyll/jekyll:builder cat
```

I tried to override this by providing arguments in my Jenkinsfile for Docker like this:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'jekyll/jekyll:builder'
      args '-v $HOME:/srv/jekyll -w /srv/jekyll'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
      sh 'cd /srv/jekyll && ls -l'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems that this just prepends the options to the Docker command and the workdir and volume mapping gets overwritten by the default settings:

```
docker run -t -d -u 127:134 
-v $HOME:/srv/jekyll 
-w /srv/jekyll 
-w /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest:rw,z 
-v /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest@tmp:/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DockerTest@tmp:rw,z 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
-e ******** 
jekyll/jekyll:builder cat
```

Is there any way that I can override the volume mappings and working directory in any way?

Comment: Please post the output of the run.

Comment: @julianlab Did you find the solution? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Nagri see below https://stackoverflow.com/a/69469421/3673430

Answer (score 3):

You can combine `docker {}` with `dir {}` to control the working directory:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'jekyll/jekyll:builder'
      args '-v $HOME:/srv/jekyll'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        dir(path: '/srv/jekyll') {
          sh 'ls -l'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've dropped the `-w` argument, since it has no effect, and replaced `cd /src/jekyll` with `dir(path: '/srv/jekyll'){...}`

Comment: when using ```dir(path: '/src')```, pipeline is failing with below. is there anything else can be done to fix this ?
```process apparently never started in /src@tmp/durable-234fa142```

Comment: it says that there is `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: What if you want that directory to be created at runtime? The goal is to let concurrent builds not to override each other's files.

Answer (score 2):

we had a same requirement to use work directory different than the default one in container, after checking it understood as of now its not possible. check here for more details [JENKINS-41474](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41474), [JENKINS-35406](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35406), [JENKINS-33510](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33510)

the other way is to use `dir("path_to_work") { sh ' '}`, but it did not worked either.
so only way is to mount the volume in container with `args` and run all the commands with change directory command in it

```
  pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'alpine:3.7'
      args '-v $HOME/src:/src'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
      sh 'cd /src ; ./run_build.sh'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nagri unfortunately I could still not specify the working directory and volume mapping.

But I could run jekylll as root.

It is not ideal but at least it works.

```
    pipeline {
        agent {
            docker {
                image 'jekyll/jekyll:builder'
                args '-u root'
            }
        }
        stages {
            stage('Test') {
                steps {
                    sh 'mkdir -p _site'
                    sh 'jekyll build'
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is not to try to set up the directory manually, since I want to execute multiple instances of the same pipeline in parallel, but to avoid node re-utilization.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#workspace-synchronization

```sh
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            // parent image: https://hub.docker.com/layers/maven/library/maven/3.6.3-jdk-11/images/sha256-1801d353e27e68d60355b371ddfd2ed8d06204bc3266f1746fdade897bb8b6bd?context=explore
            image 'fra.ocir.io/XXX/maven:3.6.3-jdk-11'
            registryUrl 'https://fra.ocir.io/'
            registryCredentialsId 'YYY'
            args '-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /opt/data/jenkins/.m2/settings.xml:/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml'

            // Create a new tmp folder for the current build
            reuseNode false
        }
    }
    environment {
        JAVA_HOME = '/usr/local/openjdk-11'
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build Test') {
            steps {
                // https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/git/
                git credentialsId: 'credentials-jenkins-gitlab',
                    url: 'git@####.git',
                    branch: 'develop-devops'

                // https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-maven/
                withMaven(
                    maven: 'maven-3.6.3',
                    jdk: 'jdk-11'
                ){
                    sh 'printenv |sort'

                    sh 'mvn help:effective-settings'

                    sh 'mvn verify'

                    sh 'echo "$(date)" >> test-file'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
            success {
                // Check if the file is dirty with previous writes
                sh 'cat test-file'

                // Clean the current workspace
                cleanWs()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue once, the problem was not the working directory, as I was using ENV variables to access my binaries from anywhere.

My issue was a permissions issue, even though I did not see any error message regarding permissions. Simply execute the command as the root user and see if that works , e.g. :

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'jekyll/jekyll:builder'
      args '-v $HOME:/srv/jekyll -w /srv/jekyll -u root'
    }
  }
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
      sh 'cd /srv/jekyll && ls -l'
      }
    }
  }
}
```